# How to install command line developer tools in Yosemite?

Tags: xcode, python, macos

I am trying to install xcode developer tools via this command:

`xcode-select --install`

and I have this error:

"Can't install this software because it is not currently available from the Software Update Server"

I am trying to install developer tools so I can use the Pillow python module. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just install them manually from Apple developer resource:  https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?=command%20line%20tools#

Comment: @IlyaIlin it's actually not there =/ and i'm in ios enroll program.

Comment: This is a roundabout way but go to Terminal and type in "gcc". This will prompt you to install developer tools

Comment: @Chip this did not work for me. I get 'gcc: no input files'

Comment: Running `xcode-select --install` worked for me after opening xcode and accepting the license agreement.